# In Advanced Installer, how to detect a 32bit process within 64bit machine?

Tags: 32bit-64bit, custom-action, advanced-installer

In [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/), how can I know if a 32bit process is running within a 64bit machine? I need to know this in order to prevent final users to install our application in given scenarios. Our approach is to use [custom actions](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/custom-actions.html) to detect if a given process is running, but it seems that Advanced installer isn't able to recognizes the ".exe *32" in the string end. Does someone know how to proceed in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct approach. To stop users from installing the application on 64 bit machines you need to go to **Launch Conditions** page and uncheck all the 64-bit OS-es from the list. This will make your package to stop from installing on 64-bit machines.

Of course, for clients running a 64-bit OS you need to create a new setup package, that contains the 64-bit version of your application. For this package set the package type **64-bit AMD** from **Install Parameters** page. Also, in **Launch Conditions** page make sure you uncheck all the 32-bit OS-es.

Comment: Nice. I'll check this approach. Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

If you're really using a custom action to detect a particular 32-bit process, it's nothing to do with Advanced Installer. Your code enumerates the processes to find the one you want, does an OpenProcess() to get a handle and then calls IsWoW64Process, and closes the handle. If you have an x64 MSI file it won't install on a 32-bit system anyway, so I'm assuming that you are trying to prevent your x64 MSI file from installing on a 64-bit system if a certain 32-bit process is running.